# How to install experimental package?

Tags: linux, debian, apt-get

I would like to install an experimental Debian package.

I'm currently having problems with the older version so I figured it's best to upgrade and try that one because I can always switch back.
Anyway I want to install this package:

```
Experimental: http://packages.debian.org/experimental/deluge
Normal: http://packages.debian.org/wheezy/deluge
```

I have wheezy debian.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Add

```
deb http://ftp.debian.org/debian experimental main contrib non-free
```

to your `/etc/apt/sources.list` or into `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/experimental.list` then execute

```
apt-get update
apt-get -t experimental install deluge
```

See [Debian Wiki](http://wiki.debian.org/DebianExperimental) and `apt-get` manual

> ```
>   -t, --target-release, --default-release
>        This option controls the default input to the policy engine; it creates a default pin at priority 990 using the specified release
>        string. This overrides the general settings in /etc/apt/preferences. Specifically pinned packages are not affected by the value of
>        this option. In short, this option lets you have simple control over which distribution packages will be retrieved from. Some
>        common examples might be -t '2.1*', -t unstable or -t sid. Configuration Item: APT::Default-Release; see also the
>        apt_preferences(5) manual page.
> ```